# Cannot Send Emails with Amazon AWS, SES and PostFix

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, postfix-mta, amazon-ses

I am trying to send emails with my verified address (usertest@gmail.com), using an Ubuntu AWS Instance with postFix & Amazon SES but It is not working with postfix.

1) I've downloaded an "Amazon Simple Email Service Scripts" from [this site](http://aws.amazon.com/code/8945574369528337)

I followed the guide, and I can send emails using the following line:

> ./ses-send-email.pl --verbose -k aws-credentials -s "Test from SES" -f
>   usertest@gmail.com usertest@gmail.com

so everything works good.

2) I've installed postfix, and I added the following line into /etc/postfix/master.cf in order to integrate the point 1

> aws-email unix - n n - - pipe flags=R user=usertest
>   argv=/opt/amazon-mail/ses-send-email.pl -r -k
>   /opt/amazon-mail/aws-credentials -e
>   https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -f usertest@gmail.com
>   ${recipient}

and then I added into /etc/postfix/main.cf

> default_transport = aws-email

but when I try to send an email using:

```
echo test | mail -s "test email sent" usertest@gmail.com
```

I don't receive the email because postfix automatically remplaces the sender email address from usertest@gmail.com to root@gmail.com and root@gmail.com is not a verified email.

Also I've tried to set an alias in /etc/aliases but postfix doesn't replace root by usertest.

I only want to send some emails with my gmail email address in my PHP site allocated in a AWS Micro Instance. Its my first time in Amazon Cloud World, I think, I am doing something wrong here.

Could you help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't receive the email because postfix automatically remplaces the sender email address from 
>   usertest@gmail.com to root@gmail.com and root@gmail.com is not a verified email.

This is because you are sending from a Unix system account (signed in as root).

> Also I've tried to set an alias in /etc/aliases but postfix doesn't replace root by usertest.

That's correct. You need a Mail Delivery Agent such as Dovecot with virtual users for Dovecot to authenticate them against Postfix, or you would have to create a Unix user account by that name and su to that user.

Comment: NightKnight thanks for your reply. But when I will send email trough my public php site, wich user will be used to send the email? root user too?.

Comment: The user that is running the php service (the process owner). You can find it out using $processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print_r($processUser); [Please vote if I am being helpful]

Comment: This should also work: <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks
I solved using sender_canonical_maps in main.cf postfix's file.